# Getting warning when composer update or composer install

Tags: laravel

I get the errors when I'm using the command `composer install` or `composer update`, it's still working fine, but I want to know why I get this warning? I just want to avoid this help, you can see the warning as below
[image: see my warning as this image]

Answer (score -1):

It means that you are using a package that is itself with the status `abandoned` or has dependencies with the status `abandoned`. Most likely those packages won't get bug fixing, security fixes, or upgrades anymore.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#abandoned

To fix it, you need to dig into your `composer.json` and the `composer.json` of each dependency to see where those `abandoned` packages are being called.

You can use this neat function to see your tree of dependencies to see the culprit packages:

```
composer show --tree
```